# tablesorter calculate percentage difference between rows

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to calculate the percentage difference between `ASK` and `BID`  on every `row` and have it displayed on column `DIFF` using `widget-math.js`.

Here's my table:

[image]

I've this options set :

```
   widgets: ["zebra", "filter", 'math'],
            widgetOptions : {             
  math_data     : 'math', // data-math attribute
  math_ignore   : [0, 1],
  math_complete : function($cell, wo, result) {
    var pct = result;
    return pct ;
    }
```

This function:

```
    $.tablesorter.equations['custom'] = function(arry) {
        // (a+b+c)*d - (e/f)*100

       return 100 * (arry[4]/arry[5]) / arry[4];
   };
```

The html looks like:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>EXCHANGE</th> 
    <th>PAIR</th> 
    <th>ASK QUANTITY</th> 
    <th>ASK TOTAL</th> 
    <th>ASK</th> 
    <th>BID</th> 
    <th>BID TOTAL</th> 
    <th>BID QUANTITY</th> 
    <th>DIFF</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody>     <tr>
        <th>Liqui.io</th>
        <th>AE/ETH</th>
        <td>201.0782718600</td>
        <td>0.2855070166</td>
        <td>0.0014198800</td>
        <td>0.0013974500</td>
        <td>0.0100000000</td>
        <td>7.1558910900</td>
        <td data-math="row-custom"></td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <th>Etherdelta</th>
        <th>AE/ETH</th>
        <td>3.741.9966441793</td>
        <td>5.5344130367</td>
        <td>0.0014790000</td>
        <td>0.0013830000</td>
        <td>0.3071114810</td>
        <td>222.0618083940</td>
        <td data-math="row-custom"></td>
    </tr></tbody> 
</table>
```

For some reason it displays a blank cell. Any idea of what's wrong ?

---

**Info:**

> tablesorter  version : '2.28.15'
>   jQuery Version: 3.2.1

Comment: I *think* it's working for me - https://jsfiddle.net/uke86wLw/2/. The `arry[4]` and `arry[5]` are targeting the "BID TOTAL" and "BID QUANTITY" columns - the first two columns are ignored due to `math_ignore`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working. What jquery version are you using?

Comment: That demo (since I wasn't paying attention) is using v1.11.0. I switched it to use latest (jQuery-git which is v3.2.2-pre) and it still works leading me to think the jQuery version doesn't matter.